# Replace all selected content with html in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a set of selected elements using:

```
$(selector).nextUntil('tr.some_class');
```

And I want to be able to replace the entire contents with new HTML.

jQuery has replaceWith and replaceAll methods, which will replace each element with the selected html, but I'm not trying to insert html into each element, I'm trying to to a mass HTML replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$(selector).nextUntil('tr.some_class').remove().append("<blah>");
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming you want both the `selector` and `tr.some_class` TRs to remain (the behavior of nextUntil) AND that `selector` identifies a single row, you can do this like so:

```
$("tr#id1").nextUntil('tr.some_class').remove();
$("tr#id1").after("<tr><td>g</td><td>g1</td></tr>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6WTNr/4/

Comment: I like chaining methods with jquery, but sometimes it's nicer to be able to replace the contents of an element in a single call. I'm not sure if calling .remove().append() is faster than just calling .html(), but I suspect it might.

Comment: remove().append() didn't work for me either. It removed the contents correctly, but appended the contents further down the table rows instead of the exact same location.

Answer (score 1):

```
var your_markup = "<div>hello world</div>";
$(selector).nextUntil('tr.some_class').html(your_markup);
```

Comment: This does something very similar to replaceWith in that it replaces the HTML of each matched element in nextUntil instead of replacing the entire HTML.